# How to select visible elements with specific attributes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Suppose there is a div containing some 'li' elements. when I click on a checkbox, some elements(li) get selected.I want to select all the li having some specific attributes from the li's which are visible in the div.
For example below, suppose that only first three li's are visible, I want to select li having value=ItemA and color=Red.

>

```
 <div id="products">
<li value="ItemA" color="Yellow"><img src="images/1.jpg"></li>
<li value="ItemA" color="Red"><img src="images/2.jpg"></li>
<li value="ItemB" color="Red"><img src="images/3.jpg"></li>
<li value="BRAND C" color="Red"><img src="images/7.jpg"></li>
<li value="BRAND D" color="Blue"><img src="images/8.jpg"></li>
<li value="BRAND A" color="Yellow"><img src="images/9.jpg"></li>
<li value="BRAND B" color="Yellow"><img src="images/10.jpg"></li>
</div>
```

I know these queries.

```
$("#products").find("li:visible")      //query to find visible li

$('li[value="ItemA"][color="Red"]).hide()   // query with attribute selectors
```

What will be the jquery statement to select such li.

Comment: So you want to combine those two `$('li[value="ItemA"][color="Red"]:visible')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value` and `color` are invalid attributes for `li` element, you can use `data-*` attributes instead:

```
<li data-value="itema" data-color="red"><img src="images/1.jpg"></li>
```

Then you can use `:visible` selector to select visible elements.

```
$('#products li[data-value="itema"][data-color="red"]:visible');
```

This is a long and slow selector, but selects the elements you want.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want all the visible elements that are `ItemA` and `Red`, just use

```
$('li[value="ItemA"][color="Red"]:visible')
```

but like @undefined said, you shouldn't use `color` and `value` attributes, and instead use proper [html5 data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), `data-color` and `data-value`.

```
<li data-value="ItemA" data-color="Red"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.filter()` function

```
$('li[value="ItemA"][color="Red"]').filter(':visible');
```

OR

```
$('li[value="ItemA"][color="Red"]').filter(function() {
            return $(this).is(':visible');
})
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fCarQ/)**